# Session is not maintained when page gets redirected in my localhost

Tags: php, session, session-timeout

Session is not maintained when page gets redirected to another in my localhost,
I have a admin login page of my osCommerce v2.0 site, whenever i login its the session registered in login page is not found in index page hence redirected back to login page...
Please guide me why this happening in my localhost and not in my server?

Comment: Is session.save_path pointing to a folder that exists?

Comment: have you put on `session_start()` on your pages?

Comment: The same thing is working perfectly in main server without particularised declaration of session_start in this page.. hence this proves that it is all set in its configuration file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a php.ini setting called [session.auto_start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start), more than likely that is set on your main server.

Comment: +1 Sometimes I feel that GOD forgot to script the conflict script script for my silly brain :) thanxxxx cmendoza

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be with the cookies not being sent back by the browser, "localhost" has caused me problems with this in the past.  This is something to do with the fact that you don't have a period in the domain name which is required by the spec IIRC (you obviously do in the real server which is why it works there).

Open `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add an alias:

`127.0.0.1    server.local`

Alter your osCommerce config as necessary and try accessing the page again via server.local and see what happens.

Comment: I cannot select two answers as accepted but your reply also helped me to resolve my problem thanks again, But here i would like to know why is the case it needs the period in domain name?

Comment: It's in the spec, http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2965: "[the hostname string] is a [Host Domain Name] string and has the form NB, where N is a non-empty name string, B has the form .B', and B' is a HDN string."

Answer (score 0):

I found that changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 allowed the session to be maintained and fixed this issue on WAMP running on a Windows 8.1 tablet.

You then simply need to update the configure.php files in both admin and catalog to change all references to localhost to 127.0.0.1